# WordCloud color based on other data column

Tags: r, graph, rstudio, word-cloud

I'm looking to apply a world cloud function but change the color formatting based on another attribute.

Here is how my data d looks, obviously I have many more city names.
The idea is that I would like to have the size of the words based on the number of freq but the colors of the words be based on the 'year' column.
This means that paris and nyc would be the same color, and tokyo and rome would have the same color too.

```
name    freq    year  status
paris   5       2010  booked
nyc     25      2010  booked
tokyo   10      2011  notbooked
rome    9       2011  notbooked

wordcloud(words = d$name, freq = d$freq, min.freq = 1,scale = c(2, 0.2),
                    max.words=200, random.order=FALSE, rot.per=0.1, 
                     colors=brewer.pal(8, "Dark2"))
```

Howevere for now I dont see how to introduce d$year in the wordcloud function. Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you say that you wanted tokyo & rome to have the same color,  I assume that you meant to have the year for rome to be 2011.

```
df=read.table(text="name    freq    year
paris   5       2010
nyc     25      2010
tokyo   10      2011
rome    9       2011",
header=TRUE)

library(wordcloud)
wordcloud(words = df$name, freq = df$freq, min.freq = 1,scale = c(2, 0.2),
                    max.words=200, random.order=FALSE, rot.per=0.1, 
                    ordered.colors=TRUE,
                     colors=brewer.pal(8, "Dark2")[factor(df$year)])
```

[image: Word Cloud]

Comment: Great! thank you so much for both correcting & solving :)

Comment: any idea if we can force the different year groups to be near each other? so for example 2010 top left corner, 2011 top right corner etc? @G5W

Comment: I do not believe that you can control the placement of the words.  However,  there is a random element so if you run the same wordcloud statement repeatedly, you will get different layouts. Try several.

Comment: Got it, it wont make perfect groups but some re-runs are better than other.

@G5W last question: do you know how I could add the legend on the side of the graph to show which year corresponds to which color? Thank you so much for all your help.

Comment: `legend("topright", legend = levels(factor(df$year)),
 text.col=brewer.pal(8, "Dark2")[unique(factor(df$year))])`